# What does "match ref" mean in rust?

Tags: rust

```
fn main () {

   let x: &Option<_> = &Some(90);

    match x {
        // no ref
        &Some(y) => { 
            print!("{}", y);
        },
        &None => { 
        
        },
    }
    
    match x {
        // ref
        &Some(ref y) => { 
            print!("{}", y);
        },
        &None => { 
        
        },
    }
    
}
```

// What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can (and should) format source code with the `{}` (Code Sample) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ref` is inverse of `&` on the left side of match. In other words:

```rust
let ref a = x;
```

Is the same as

```rust
let a = &x;
```

The reason for that syntax is that with structural matching it is not always possible to use 2nd form:

```rust
struct Foo(usize);

let Foo(ref a) = x;
```